# Unable to plot dataframe (Output not excepted)

Tags: python

I try to plot the following dataframe :

```
3     2019.0   2020.0    2021.0 2022.0 2023.0 2024.0
NaN
S1     -78.876  -145.006 -336.5790 -187.5  -156   -114
S2      91.453    74.644  177.9077     93   224    383
```

doing :
DF.plot(kind="bar")
but I get as output :

[image]

This is not the output excepted.

The output excepted would be stuff like that :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot the two Series successively:

```
df.loc['S1'].plot(kind='bar')
df.loc['S2'].plot(kind='bar', color='#FF7F0E')
plt.legend()
```

*NB. if you really want S2 on the bottom use `-df`*

[image]

Used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'2019': [-78.876, 91.453],
                   '2020': [-145.006, 74.644],
                   '2021': [-336.579, 177.9077],
                   '2022': [-187.5, 93.0],
                   '2023': [-156, 224],
                   '2024': [-114, 383]}, index=['S1', 'S2'])
```

Comment: I have the following
KeyError: 'S1'

Comment: Is the first column a column or the index? If not the index, use `df.set_index('NaN')` or whatever the type is to ensure having it as index

Comment: Alternatively, can you provide the output of `df.to_dict()` for explicitness?

Comment: Thank you v much it did the trick. Last question there is a 3 just before 'NaN' See edited question. How would I change this '3' to a 'abcd' string ? I tryied to reset index but did not delete the 3..

Comment: hard to answer with just text, best would be to provide the output of `df.to_dict()`. Right now it looks like index names which don't matter